# Disable E-Mail for Virtual Products in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

is there any option to disable the E-Mail (download_product) that will be sent when a customer purchased a Virtual Product?

i already managed to add the Download "visible" in the Order itself. And the Link for the Download i could move to the Confirmation Mail. There is no Problem to get the Download for the Customer. Just need to know which File from Prestashop is sending the Mail for the Virtual Product to access the Download, so i can disable that one.
Until now i can not find :-/

Any suggestions are welcome and very helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **classes/order/OrderHistory.php** for

```
               Mail::Send(
                    (int) $order->id_lang,
                    'download_product',
                    Context::getContext()->getTranslator()->trans(
                        'The virtual product that you bought is available for download',
                        [],
                        'Emails.Subject',
                        $orderLanguage->locale
                    ),
                    $data,
                    $customer->email,
                    $customer->firstname . ' ' . $customer->lastname,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    _PS_MAIL_DIR_,
                    false,
                    (int) $order->id_shop
                );
```

Comment: i comment this part out and works like a charm, thank you. :-)